# Can't import some excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a code to help me import Excel spreadsheets with a click of a button. The code works and I can import most Excel spreadsheets. However, there are some Excel spreadsheet that I am unable to import and I can't figure out why.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub btnBrowse_Click()
    Dim diag As Office.FileDialog
    Dim item As Variant

    Set diag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    diag.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diag.Title = "Please select an Excel Spreadsheet"
    diag.Filters.Clear
    diag.Filters.Add "Excel Spreadsheet", "*.xls, *.xlsx"

    If diag.Show Then
        For Each item In diag.SelectedItems
            Me.txtFileName = item
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnHome_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm ("MainFrm")
End Sub

Private Sub btnImport_Click()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject

    If Nz(Me.txtFileName, "") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a file"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FileExists(Nz(Me.txtFileName, "")) Then
        ImportExcel.ImportExcelSpreadsheet Me.txtFileName, FSO.GetFileName(Me.txtFileName)
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found"

    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ImportExcelSpreadsheet(fileName As String, tableName As String)
On Error GoTo BadFormat
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tableName, fileName, True
    Exit Sub

BadFormat:
    MsgBox "The file you tried to import was not an Excel Spreadsheet"
End Sub
```

Some of the excel spreadsheet files that I cannot import will display the message that I typed in the code. The file type is definitely an Excel spreadsheet but I somehow can't import. I am wondering if it is because of my code.

Comment: It is. But we don't have your `ImportExcel.ImportExcelSpreadsheet` function.

Comment: @Gustav added the function, will appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Try to import file via MS Access master, manually, would you get same error or not?

Comment: @VanNg I didn't get the error when I did it manually

Comment: Switch on raising on all erros option like here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKUWf.png After that you can get more details about what an error do you get

Answer (score 0):

The *SpreadsheetType* should be `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml`, at least as the first attempt.

Comment: Hi, I tried using this but i still have the same issue

Comment: Then those spreadsheets are malstructured somehow or not of the Excel12 format.

Comment: Are the problematic spreadsheets of the right type?  Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acspreadsheettype)

Comment: @SiyonDP they are .xlsx type

Comment: But we don't have them. So, double-check for peculiarities.

Comment: OK, Your custom error msg is not in place, since it doesn't reveal what went wrong. Your next step is to check the Error Message. Add under `BadFormat:` label the   `... & Err.description` to the MsgBox alert

Comment: @SiyonDP Hi, thanks this was helpful. It turns out one of the columns does not have a valid name. I am trying to figure out why only that column has an invalid field name.